# Swift can lazy and didSet set together

Tags: swift

I have a property

```
public lazy var points: [(CGFloat,CGFloat,CGFloat)] = {
        var pointsT = [(CGFloat,CGFloat,CGFloat)]()
        let height = 100.0
        for _ in 1...10 {
            pointsT.append((someValue,someValue,100.0))
        }
        return pointsT
    }()
```

And i want to add a `didSet` method, is it possible?

Comment: what is `ar` in `for p in ar`?

Comment: Changed it, nothing to do with the question actually. thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Try out this simple example in some class or method of yours:

```
lazy var myLazyVar: Int = {
    return 1
} () {
    willSet {
        print("About to set lazy var!")
    }
}
```

This gives you the following compile time error:

> Lazy properties may not have observers.

---

With regard to the `let` statement in the other answer: lazy variable are not necessary just *"let constants with delayed initialisation"*. Consider the following example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var myInt = 1

    mutating func increaseMyInt() {
        myInt += 1
    }

    lazy var myLazyVar: Int = {
        return self.myInt
    } ()
}

var a = MyStruct()
print(a.myLazyVar) // 1
a.increaseMyInt()
print(a.myLazyVar) // 1: "initialiser" only called once, OK
a.myLazyVar += 1
print(a.myLazyVar) // 2: however we can still mutate the value
                   //    directly if we so wishes
```

Comment: You are absolutely right about that, will remove that from my answer which then basically reads "no" :) up you go!

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is as other have said is "no" but there is a way to get the effect using a private lazy var and computed var.

```
private lazy var _username: String? = {
    return loadUsername()
}()
var username: String? {
    set {
        // Do willSet stuff in here
        if newValue != _username {
            saveUsername(newValue)
        }
        // Don't forget to set the internal variable
        _username = newValue
        // Do didSet stuff here
        // ...
    }
    get {
        return _username
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Started by version Swift 5.3 Property observers can now be attached to lazy properties.

```swift
class C {
  lazy var property: Int = 0 {
    willSet { print("willSet called!") } // Okay
    didSet { print("didSet called!") } // Okay
  }
}

or

class C {
  lazy var property: Int = { return 0 }() {
    willSet { print("willSet called!") } // Okay
    didSet { print("didSet called!") } // Okay
  }
}
```

Please take a look at the links below for more:

1. https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/lazy-property-observers/
2. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to show _how_ to do this instead of **relying primarily on a link** to demonstrate the functionality?

Comment: Webpages often die, please include the content of your answer here rather than a link to external sites.

Answer (score 3):

**No**

<s>`points` is a constant, you cannot set anything to it. The only difference to a `let` constant is that it is (potentially) initialized later.</s>

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27886111/2442804) provides a little more information as to why you use `var` instead of `let` in the `lazy` case.

*Edit: to make the answer not look to empty*
Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.codingexplorer.com/swift-property-observers/) where the author raises a few valid points regarding why observing `lazy` vars might not *yet* be supported. What should `oldValue` be in the observer? `nil`? That would not be a good idea in your non-optional case.

Comment: *"The only difference to a let constant is that it is (potentially) initialised later"*, this is not really true. The lazy vars can be used as `var`:s just as well, see my added example.

Comment: Regarding the edit: I agree, good addition. Also, you were somewhat on point before in that lazy var *should* generally behave quite immutable after initialisation, since generally, we use lazy vars on (large?) class or structure instances that themselves will not change (even if their members mutate; but we can have separate observers for this). Hence, we have our own `once-only-willSet` in our initialiser of the lazy variables (e.g. print "Will be set!"). So perhaps Apple intends (convention-wise) for lazy vars to not change after init., hence another reason why there's no prop. observers.